# How to test in gitlab CI some code that is packaged in a Docker image, and that uses the Docker Python SDK?

Tags: python, docker, sdk, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I have a Python program that uses the Docker Python SDK to run a container for a third-party docker image. Something like that in my code:

```py
import docker
docker.from_env().containers.run(image="<other_image>")
```

My program is also packaged in Docker, and I would like to test with gitlab CI. So my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like that:

```yaml
image: <my_image>:latest

stages:
  - Tests

pytest:
  stage: Tests
  script:
    - pytest
```

And the python code from above is covered by the tests. The problem is that the CI fails on `docker.from_env()` with `docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))`.

I assume that is because there's no docker server accessible from within `<my_image>` container. I searched for solutions, and I found the `docker:dind` one + the "expose docker socket" i.e. `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` one, but I can't make it work.

All the examples that I found for `docker:dind` are for calling docker directly in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but I have found none that explains how to leverage it for using a Docker SDK in your own code. Also, the socket solution requires you to change the gitlab runner configuration, but I don't have access to it (I am using a gitlab free account and don't have the opportunity to host my own runner).

What I need is basically:

```yaml
image:
  name: <my_image>:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But AFAIK it doesn't exist.

Is there any solution?

Update: I realize that this would actually work:

```yaml
image: docker

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - Tests

pytest:
  stage: Tests
  script:
    - docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <my_image>:latest pytest
```

But I would still be interested to know if it's possible to do it while still using my image as the base (for example, maybe I don't want to have pytest installed in my image, but I would do it with a `before_script` instruction in `.gitlab-ci.yml`... this I could also do in a script to be executed instead of running pytest directly, so I agree that this might not be a very good reason).

Comment: Are you using `gitlab.com` shared runners or a self-hosted GitLab runner?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```yaml
image: <your python/docker-SDK image>

pytest:
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  script:
    - pytest
```

Just like regular `docker`, the SDK will [use these environment variables](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html) to configure the client correctly to use the `docker:dind` service.